# Is there any detailed Clang library API documentation?

Tags: c++, clang

I've been reading some codes which heavily uses Clang library API. However, I'm not familiar with Clang API at all and have to google it all the time. For example, when I read some code like `clang::EnumConstantDecl`, I'll follow google and go to  [this page](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1EnumConstantDecl.html). It seems that every thing about `EnumConstantDecl` can be found here, but all what I see is just a list of API(or just some function prototype) without any concrete explanation. I still have no idea how to use it.

So, is there any other good documentation? Or, is there any basic knowledge I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

What helps me the most is simply searching the LLVM/Clang source itself for usages of e.g. `clang::EnumConstantDecl` or its member and methods. It serves pretty well as a source of high-quality usage examples. Just make sure you are using an IDE that can deal with with the massive amount of code.

I doubt that there is a more efficient way to get used to this API.

Answer (score 0):

The page you link is an internal documentation of clang and it contains bits of explanation on what it is doing:

> EnumConstantDecl - An instance of this object exists for each enum
>   constant that is defined. For example, in "enum X {a,b}", each of a/b
>   are EnumConstantDecl's, X is an instance of EnumDecl, and the type of
>   a/b is a TagType for the X EnumDecl.

A documentation does not have to contain use examples. They say that explicitly on their main page:

> This documentation describes the internal software that makes up clang, not the external use of clang. There are no instructions here on how to use clang, only the APIs that make up the software. For usage instructions, please see the programmer's guide or reference manual.

However, you can look for other clang material at:

http://clang.llvm.org/docs

especially the "Using Clang as a Library" may be of use for you. However, since I don't know exactly what you are working on, I can't give you more precise pointers. I hope however, that you can take it from here...

Comment: Thanks. I want to find a detailed documentation about Clang API(its general description and some example uses of its API), but I still did not find it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing of substantially more use than the Doxygen non-documentation. You will have to just read it and make an educated guess. The Clang devs will answer questions in their IRC channel; but there's no guarantee of useful help there and they will often tell you to just read the source.